# Rendering 3d reconstructed models in ARCore

Tags: arcore, 3d-model

My objective is to create a `3d model` of a real-life object and render it in an `ARCore` app. I used `openMVG` to reconstruct the model from a series of images. The model looks almost perfect when viewed in Meshlab. But when I try to render it in an `ARCore` app, the model becomes completely messed up with random lines protruding from various places and there is almost zero smoothness in the model.

If someone faced similar issue, please help in pointing out what could be wrong. I basically reused the obj file reader and renderer code from the `ARCore` sample app.

Comment: Are you using Unity or Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio.